# How can I convert this keras cnn model to pytorch version

Tags: machine-learning, keras, artificial-intelligence, pytorch, conv-neural-network

This is the example keras code that I want to convert to pytorch. My input dataset is 10000*1*102 (two dimensions for labels). The dataset includes 10000 samples. Each sample contains one row with 102 features. I am thinking to use 1dcnn for regression.

PS: hyper-parameter (e.g. filters, kernel_size, stride, padding) could be adjusted based on my 10000*1*102 dataset.

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv1D(filters=64, kernel_size=3, activation='relu', input_shape=(n_timesteps,n_features)))
model.add(Conv1D(filters=64, kernel_size=3, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(MaxPooling1D(pool_size=2))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(100, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(n_outputs, activation='softmax'))
```

Comment: Here is a blog post that might help you in your effort. https://gereshes.com/2019/06/24/how-to-transfer-a-simple-keras-model-to-pytorch-the-hard-way/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome to pytorch. :)
I am really glad you decide to switch from Keras to PyTorch. It was an important step for me to understand how NNs work in more detail. If you have any specific questions about code or if it isn't working please let me know.

```
import torch.nn as nn
a0 = nn.Conv1D(n_timesteps, 64, 3)
a1 = nn.Relu()
b0 = nn.Conv1D(64, 64, 3)
b1 = nn.Relu()
c0 = torch.nn.Dropout(p=0.5)
d0 = nn.MaxPool1d(2)
e0 = nn.Flatten()
e1 = nn.Linear(32*n_timesteps,100)
e2 = nn.Relu()
e3 = nn.Linear(n_outputs)
f0 = nn.Softmax(dim=1)

model = nn.Sequential(a0,a1,b0,b1,c0,d0,e0,e1,e2,e3,f0)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, that was helpful.

Comment: Do I need to define it as a class ,which includes init, forward?

Comment: Pytorch supports both types, a functional programming style which is in the style of the posted answer. And a object oriented style which would require you to extend torch.nn.Module and declare init and forward.

Answer (score 0):

Name: `torch`

Version: `1.11.0.dev20211231+cu113`

This article has been very helpful. But the code seems to have changed a little as of the current standards, so I'm leaving a reply.

```
import torch.nn as nn
from torchsummary import summary as summary_

n_timesteps = 10000
n_features  = 102
n_outputs   = 1
a0 = nn.Conv1d(n_features, 64, 3)
a1 = nn.ReLU()
b0 = nn.Conv1d(64, 64, 3)
b1 = nn.ReLU()
c0 = nn.Dropout(p=0.5)
d0 = nn.MaxPool1d(2)
e0 = nn.Flatten()
e1 = nn.Linear(319872,100)
e2 = nn.ReLU()
e3 = nn.Linear(100,n_outputs)
f0 = nn.Softmax(dim=1)

model = nn.Sequential(a0,a1,b0,b1,c0,d0,e0,e1,e2,e3,f0)
model.to('cuda')
summary_(model,(n_features,n_timesteps),batch_size=1)
```