# Keras model convert into pytorch

Tags: python, keras, pytorch

```
def network():
inputs = Input(name='inputs', shape=[51, ])
layer1 = Dense(2048)(inputs)
layer1 = BatchNormalization(name='BC11')(layer1)
layer1 = Activation('relu', name='Act11')(layer1)

layer2 = Dense(1024, name='FC1')(layer1)
layer2 = BatchNormalization(name='BC1')(layer2)
layer2 = Activation('relu', name='Act1')(layer2)
layer_shortcut1 = Dense(1024, activation='relu')(inputs)
layer_shortcut1 = BatchNormalization(name='BCshortcut1')(layer_shortcut1)
layer2 = Add()([layer2, layer_shortcut1])
merge1 = concatenate([layer1, layer2])

layer3 = Dense(512, name='FC3')(merge1)
layer3 = BatchNormalization(name='BC3')(layer3)
layer3 = Activation('relu', name='Act3')(layer3)

layer4 = Dense(256, name='FC5')(layer3)
layer4 = BatchNormalization(name='BC5')(layer4)
layer4= Activation('relu', name='Act5')(layer4)
layer_shortcut2 = Dense(256, activation='relu')(layer2)
layer_shortcut2 = BatchNormalization(name='BCshortcut2')(layer_shortcut2)
layer4 = Add()([layer4, layer_shortcut2])
merge2 = concatenate([layer3, layer4])

layer5 = Dense(128, name='FC7')(merge2)
layer5 = BatchNormalization(name='BC7')(layer5)
layer5 = Activation('relu', name='Act7')(layer5)

layer6 = Dense(64, name='FC8')(layer5)
layer6 = BatchNormalization(name='BC8')(layer6)
layer6 = Activation('relu', name='Act8')(layer6)
layer_shortcut3 = Dense(64, activation='relu')(layer4)
layer_shortcut3 = BatchNormalization(name='BCshortcut')(layer_shortcut3)
layer6 = Add()([layer6, layer_shortcut3])
merge3 = concatenate([layer5, layer6])

layer7 = Dense(32, name='FC9')(merge3)
layer7 = BatchNormalization(name='BC9')(layer7)
layer7 = Activation('relu', name='Act9')(layer7)

layer8 = Dense(16, name='FC0')(layer7)
layer8 = BatchNormalization(name='BC0')(layer8)
layer8 = Activation('relu', name='Act0')(layer8)

out0 = Dense(12, activation='sigmoid', name='Out0')(merge2)
out1 = Dense(12, activation='sigmoid', name='Out1')(merge3)
out2 = Dense(12, activation='sigmoid', name='Out2')(layer8)
model = Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=[out0,out1,out2])
return model
```

I am new in pytorch. Could someone help me to convert this into pytorch? I have seen [How can I convert this keras cnn model to pytorch version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60172607/how-can-i-convert-this-keras-cnn-model-to-pytorch-version) but meet the dimension issues. Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

From [this stack overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65192453/convert-a-simple-cnn-from-keras-to-pytorch). Forward your upvotes to the OG.

You can save keras weight and reload them in pytorch. the steps are

```
Step 0: Train a Model in Keras. ...
Step 1: Recreate & Initialize Your Model Architecture in PyTorch. ...
Step 2: Import Your Keras Model and Copy the Weights. ...
Step 3: Load Those Weights onto Your PyTorch Model. ...
Step 4: Test and Save Your Pytorch Model.
```

You Can follow example here https://gereshes.com/2019/06/24/how-to-transfer-a-simple-keras-model-to-pytorch-the-hard-way/

Comment: Hi, thanks for your time.  Due to the settings of the experiment, I just cannot simply save the weights and reload them into PyTorch...To convert the code into Pytorch is the best way.